# How to print the items in a list, given through input?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, input

I have a variable that saves the user's input. If the user inputs a list, e.g `["oranges","apples","pears"]` python seems to take this as a string, and print every character, instead of every word, that the code would print if fruit was simply a list. How do I the code to do this? Here is what I've tried...

```
fruit = input("What is your favourite fruit?")
fruit = list(fruit)
for i in fruit:
  print(i)
```

Comment: `input` *always* returns a string. Use input is fundamentally a string, you have to parse that input somehow to get a useful data structure. Typically, your user shouldn't be entering things like `["oranges","apples","pears"] `, this is source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python takes inputs as one huge string so instead of that being a list it is just a string like that looks like this

```py
'["oranges","apples","pears"]'
```

turning this into a list will just look like

```py
['[', '"', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 's', '"', ',', '"', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's', '"', ',', '"', 'p', 'e', 'a', 'r', 's', '"', ']']
```

instead of this try something like this which asks for favourite fruits until you do not enter a fruit

```
Fruits = []
while True:
    temp = input()
    if temp == "":
        break
    else:
        Fruits.append(temp)
```

and then output the values

```
for x in Fruits:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split word is list by comma.

```
fruit = list(fruit.split(","))


fruit = input("What is you favourite fruit?")
fruit = fruit.split(",")
for i in fruit:
  print(i)
```

Comment: this is nto going to work with `'["oranges","apples","pears"]'`

Comment: this gives output as fruit name. But you are saying is correct, passing list as user input is not correct.